# Non-typical (?) recurrence relation: a*n*b^n in non-homogenous linear recursive equations

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I've tried to find a solution to my problem, but I didn't managed to. The thing is about non-homogenous linear equations. I've got a linear equation in the form of 
$a_n = 3 a_{n-1} + 50 a_{n-2} + 12 a_{n-3} + 216 a_{n-4} + 
8 \cdot 9^n + 6n \cdot 9^n $.

As far as I know, I can find a solution of associated homogenous linear equation, and then find solutions for others parts of problem. I found a general solution for associated homogenous linear equation, I know how to work with terms like a $8 \cdot 9^n$, but I don't have any idea how to deal with $6n \cdot 9^n$. I've searched on the internet any possible ways to deal with things like this, but I've got no answer. Can you help me?

Comment: You could use generating functions, i.e. let $A(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ and find an expression for $A(z)$ using power series.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to rewrite the equation as $$a_n = 3 a_{n-1} + 50 a_{n-2} + 12 a_{n-3} + 216 a_{n-4} + 
(8  + 6n)\,9^n$$ Solving the homogeneous equation, you noticed that $9$ is a root of the characteristic equation and since the last term is of first degree, then the general solution is of second degree.

So, let, for the particular solution, $a_n=(\alpha+\beta n +\gamma n^2)\,9^n$; replace and group terms to end with
$$(425 \beta -845 \gamma -1944)+(850 \gamma -1458) n=0$$ making $\gamma=\frac{729}{425}$ and then $\beta=\frac{288441}{36125}$ and the $\alpha$ term will be added to the coefficient of the $9^n$ term which already appeared in the solution of the  homogeneous equation.